# Told to make instance variable "Coin coin" in class "CoinStats". What is "Coin coin" and what can it do?

Tags: class, instance-variables

In my java programming course we are working with classes. I have an assignment which have basically told me to make this:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Oppgaver5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }//End main    
}//End class Oppgaver5

class Coin {
    boolean face;

    public boolean flip(){
        Random side = new Random();
        face = side.nextBoolean();
        return face;
    }//End flip       

    public boolean getFace(){
        return face;
    }//End getFace    
}//End class Coin
```

This i understood. But the next part tells me to make another class, CoinStats, and the instance variable Coin coin. I cant wrap my head around what that is supposed to be. What can you use that for?

```
class CoinStats{
    Coin coin;
    String history;
```

The rest of what im supposed to do for the assingment, if that makes it easier to answear:

```
    public boolean flipCoin(){
    //Flips the coin and saves the result with addResult
    }//End flipCoin

    public boolean getFace(){
    //returns which side of the coin is up now    
    }//End getFace

    private void addResult(boolean result){
    //saves the result in history
    }//End addResult

    public String getHistory(){
    //Returns the history object
    }//End getHistory

}//End class CoinStats
```

Comment: They are asking you to use a variable named `coin` who's type is `Coin` (the class you just defined). The syntax `Coin coin` is how you declare this new variable and specify what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

`Coin coin` means "create an instance of the class Coin and name it 'coin'". It's pretty normal in java, to name the variables after their classes, if you only use one instance of it. After that, you can access the methods `coin.flip` and `coin.getFace` inside your `CoinStats` class.

You could also instance the class with `Coin dollar`. Then the methods were called by `dollar.flip` and `dollar.getFace`. You could even instance it with `Coin CoinStat` and use the methods `CoinStat.flip` and `CoinStat.getFace`, but it's bad practice to start variable names with upper cases, because it will confuse you.

Comment: yes. you could also make it shorter and use `public Boolean flipCoin(){ return coin.flip();}`.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I should be able to do this: `class CoinStats{
    Coin coin;
    
    public boolean flipCoin(){
    boolean result = coin.flip();
    return result;}}` and return either `true` or `false` But when I do this I get a Null Pointer Exception.  If I set `Coin coin = new Coin();`, then it works...

Comment: sorry, I missed that. Yes, you have to call the constructor of Coin with `Coin coin = new Coin();` even if you didn't code a constructor for that class.